# Gradle:run Task failing [Gluon javafx]

Tags: java, android, gradle, gluon, javafx-11

I just created a starter project using Intellji Idea. And the gradle build and tasks were created successfully too .
**Details :** 
gradle : `5.1.0` 
jvm : `11` 
javafx : `11` 
Here's the `build.gradle` file used in the starter project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' , 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.mainapplication.Application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        androidSdk = 'D:\\@games'
        applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

When i perform the task `gettingstartedApp:run` am getting this following error.

```
Executing task 'run'...

> Task :wrapper

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Task :gettingStartedApp:compileJava
> Task :gettingStartedApp:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gettingStartedApp:classes
> Task :gettingStartedApp:configJavafxRun
> Task :gettingStartedApp:compileDesktopJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gettingStartedApp:processDesktopResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :gettingStartedApp:desktopClasses UP-TO-DATE

> Task :gettingStartedApp:run FAILED
Error: --module-path requires module path specification

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gettingStartedApp:run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I even added `--module-path \path\javafx\lib` to gradle VM options in Intellji Idea gradle configuration and am still getting this error.
Please help me fix this Issue ,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Both plugins jfxmobile and javafx-gradle-plugin collide with each other, as the former moves every dependency to the classpath and leaves an empty `--module-path` option in the command line, which causes the exception. The jfxmobile plugin is for Java 1.8. For Java 11+, you should check the new Gluon client plugin, starting here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples.

Comment: thanks , i will give these examples a try @JoséPereda

Comment: ```[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.20:build (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error, client:build failed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.20:build (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error, client:build failed``` got error on `mvn clean client:build` @JoséPereda

Comment: As stated in the readme, at the moment you need a Linux (for Linux/Android) or Mac OS (for Mac OS/iOS) machine. Did you check the list of prerequisites?

Comment: yes i did saw and i ran this command on wsl $bash  @JoséPereda ,

Comment: Hmm, [the Ubuntu that runs under Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux is not a full distro. In fact, it's not Linux at all -- it has no Linux kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051537). You need at least to use a VM like VirtualBox.

Comment: is there any way to run on windows @JoséPereda ?

Comment: Support for Windows is on the roadmap, but not there yet.

Comment: okay thanks @JoséPereda